# ActionScript3 FLV Player Video Transparency show on HTML Page

Tags: html, actionscript-3, actionscript, flv

I have a website project as example: http://websiteactorlive.com

I Need fully transparent Background (any) FLV Player with AS3. I have a transparent videos, but, I am adding video in FLV Player with `wmode=transparent` command on HTML.

I could not transparent video on HTML.
I have tried Flowplayer and JWPlayer

Also, I have [this](http://activeden.net/item/video-player-reflection-multi-skin-local-youtube/114037) product, but product developer said to me:

> It doesn't support transparent. You can do it only by editing the videoplayer.fla code

how can I add Which codes for transparency? or Anyone know another methods for this problem?